# How to use mobile vertical stepper from "@material-ui"?

Tags: react-native

I am looking to implement a vertical stepper in my `react-native` app, I found it here on the [material UI website](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/steppers.html#steppers-types-of-steppers) that "the vertical stepper can be used in the mobile as-is", however, I can't find any example usage, I also tried to import `Stepper` from `@material-ui/core` to my react native project, which didn't work (it looks like material UI is not compatible with native app).

My app is using `react-native-paper` which has a "progressBar" component but not a stepper I am looking for.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The link you provided is to material.io (Material Design) not material-ui.com (Material-UI). Material-UI can be used for mobile web apps but not for native mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

React Native Stepper
Typescript friendly, Material UI Stepper implementation in React Native.

The aim is to develop with all features of stepper as provided in the Material UI Guidelines. But, the v1 does not have all those features. But ready to be used in production as an alternative.

For the time being, only vertical stepper is supported.

View [demo here](https://snack.expo.dev/@mocioun/react-native-material-ui-stepper):

Installation

```
yarn add@material.ui/react-native-stepper
```

or

```
npm i@material.ui/react-native-stepper --save
```

Usage

```
import { StepperContainer, StepView } from '@material.ui/react-native-stepper'
```

and

```
<StepperContainer>
  <StepView title='Intro' subTitle='The intro details'>
    <Text>Step 1 Contents</Text>
  </StepView>
  <StepView title='Second' onNext={() => true} subTitle='Name and other details'>
    <Text>Step 2 Contents</Text>
  </StepView>
  <StepView title='Third Step' subTitle='Some lines'>
    <Text>Step 3 Contents …!</Text>
  </StepView>
  <StepView title='Last Step' subTitle='Finishing lines'>
    <Text>Step 4 Contents …!</Text>
  </StepView>
</StepperContainer>
```

Source Code: https://github.com/vazra/react-native-stepper